# CakePHP3, Saving current date on user registration

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP3,I'm having trouble figuring out how to save the current DATE in (year, day, month) format. I'm using mySQL as the database, and I have a users table with a created_at column with type DATE. When a user registers, how do I save the current date along with all the other entity data? I've been looking around but the CakePHP Cookbook is a little unclear.

Comment: what are you trying now ,please show your code it will be easy to recognize your problems

Comment: check this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html) Here you find more info about timestamps

Answer (score 0):

change the datatype of created_at to TIMESTAMP and set the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on the field settings.This should allow mysql to automatically set the current server date and time for you everytime a new record is created.

No code required!!!

Comment: This would work, but doesn't answer the question (note also, you [don't need to change the field type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)). It doesn't help the very next time they need to save a date, and they can't use `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.